# jquery : progress bar show in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-progressbar

my progress bar is working perfect when i write value into my html but it it dont work when i pass value from jquery .. e.g  $('#progresslevel').html(data);

right now i have this html in which if i insert value into  my progress bar  it works

```
   <span class="demo-progress" data-progress-options='{"size":false,"style":"large","barClasses":["green-gradient","glossy"],"innerMarks":25,"stripes":true,"darkStripes":false}'>50%</span>
```

[image]

but if i do this in jquery

here i am getting a value from controller

```
  $('.demo-progress').html(data);
```

it didnt work .. only 50 is written on box and nothing else .. progress bar dont appear

i tried this also by giving a div after span class and then pass value to the div but still it didnt work

anyone know how to fix this issue

Comment: is there a reason you aren't using the `progress` element and just setting its `value` property?

Comment: nope there is no any reason ..i just want to display the dynamic progress bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be directly modifying the progress bar's component elements yourself. The Progressbar widget has an [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/) that you can use to modify the progress -- specifically, you are supposed to set the [`value`](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#option-value) option:

```
$(".demo-progress").progressbar("option", "value", 50);
```

Comment: thankyou ... i did this but it didnt workout $(document ).ready(function(){
      
  $.getJSON('http://localhost/userinfo/battery_level/', function(data){
         $(".demo-progress").progressbar("option", "value", data);
          
        });
      

    });

Comment: @hellosheikh The answer given by Jon is exactly what yo need. You can also see the bin here, which validates his answer : http://jsbin.com/ujopul/1/edit . Remember to `run with js` . Secondtly are u sure , what you are using is a jquery-smooth progress bar, looks to me it might be something else. Also, why are you appending `data` to it. In case, you want to pass a value, then don't you need to retrieve the value using `data.value` or something ...

Comment: thankyu thankyou ... i got it... it works now ... thankyou very much

Comment: i dont know exactly i am using but i worked it by doing this $(".demo-progress").progress(50);