# jquery get data using jquery.load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

i have a problem similar to my previous question but now its different

[jquery : progress bar show in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281023/jquery-progress-bar-show-in-html/18281071?noredirect=1#comment26817803_18281071)

```
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(
   function ()
  {
     $('#battery').load('https=://localhost/userinfo/battery_level/');

 }, 10000);
```

i dont want to load the div ... i want to get the result and want to display in my progress bar here

```
 $('.demo-progress').progress(data);
```

i am geting a value here "10"

want to do something like this

```
 var auto_refresh = setInterval(
   function ()
  {
    var data =  $('#battery').load('https=://localhost/userinfo/battery_level/');

 }, 10000);
      $('.demo-progress').progress(data);
```

Comment: What's in your batter_level file?

Comment: its a controller name which is sending just the value ... for example 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({ max: 100, value: 10 });
            $("#twenty").click(function () { loadFile("20"); });
            $("#fifty").click(function () { loadFile("55"); });
            $("#eighty").click(function () { loadFile("80"); });
        });


        function loadFile(file) {
            $.get(file + ".txt", function (data) {
                var value = parseInt(data, 10);
                $('#progressbar').progressbar("option", "value", value);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="progressbar">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="twenty" value="Load to 20%" />
    <input type="button" id="fifty" value="Load to 50%" />
    <input type="button" id="eighty" value="Load to 80%" />
</body>
</html>
```

From the jquery page:

> This method (.load) is the simplest way to fetch data from the server.
>   It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it
>   is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit
>   callback function.

The reason why I am using .get is because of the last part, the implicit callback function, which let's me know when the function has ended, and I can then update the progressbar.

Comment: i dont want to use get .. as i want to show the real time data without page refresh .. and i think by using ur code i have to refresh the page for the result

Comment: Why don't you try it first? This will not refresh the page.

Comment: oooookkk let me try it

Comment: nope not working... well i think u should give some time interval .. dont u ... as yet it is not giving me the value without refresh

Comment: are you sure you are calling .progressbar method correctly? You have it different in the other question `$(".demo-progress").progressbar("option", "value", 50);` so maybe its `$(".demo-progress").progressbar("option", "value", data);`

Comment: well the progress bar is working fine ... but if i change the value in db then the progress bar dont change until i refresh by using ur code .. so i am running write now both the codes for testing .. the code which is mine is changing the value without refresh .. but i dont know how can i add that into progress bar .. and in ur code the  value didnt change until i refresh the page ..

Comment: Then you just need to know how to change the value of a progressbar after it has been initialized. Gimme a minute to read the documentation of the plugin.

Comment: i have commented there that what works for me ...well progress bar is displaying correct but for example write now the progress bar has 50 % ... so if the value gets 90 .. the progess bar didnt increase until i reload .. and i think its only possible if i use jquery.load

Comment: i want to explain u little more ... look by using jquery.load .. whatever value i change into db ... it just show on the page .. no need for refresh .. but in jquery.load the only problem is that i cant get or capture the result and save into some variable  .. because if i am able to get the result then i will just the pass the value into progress barden its will work

Comment: Look at this example: http://hamletsoft.net/progressbar/ I just created that with the .get function. I will upload all of the code here now. This gets a file with the .get function, gets its data and updates the progressbar.

Comment: sorry sir i think u didnt get it wat i want to say... ok let me ask u a question ... leave the progress bar .. for example if i use .get function and i in result i get data for example "hello world" ..hello world is displaying on the page right now .. and now u change the hello world to "world" from db .. will it change here without reloading the page

Comment: certainly not .. u have to reload the page if u want to see the changes .. but in case of jquery.load u dont need to reload the page

Comment: I am obviously not understanding... lets chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34705/lets-solve-this